# Android error: W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to hacker-news.firebaseio.com/2600:1901:0:94b6:::443

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, api

I'm trying to connect to a firebase api for my android project, and i'm getting this error. Im sure the code is should work but there is probably something i'm missing.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.yingli.newsreader;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        try{
            task.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty");
        }catch(Exception e){

        }

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";

            URL url;

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try{

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                int data = inputStreamReader.read();

                while(data != -1){
                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = inputStreamReader.read();



                }

                Log.i("URL content", result);

                return result;

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml i have added internet permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

this is the error im getting

```
01-09 16:08:15.733 12386-12405/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x99b050c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x99b03230)
01-09 16:08:15.847 12386-12405/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x99b050c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x99b03230)
01-09 16:12:30.349 12386-12403/com.example.yingli.newsreader W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to hacker-news.firebaseio.com/2600:1901:0:94b6:::443
01-09 16:12:30.349 12386-12403/com.example.yingli.newsreader W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:143)
```

Is there anything i'm not doing?
Thanks for your time